# How to fix Katalon error - No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.windows.keyword.WindowsBuiltinKeywords.findElements()

Tags: katalon-studio

Below is my script:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('https://xyz.xy/shop')
WebUI.delay(5)
List<WebElement> foundElements = Windows.findElements(findTestObject('Trial/ShopSearchResultPage/div-ProductInSearchResult'))
```

In Katalon, I am getting the following error message :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.windows.keyword.WindowsBuiltinKeywords.findElements() is applicable for argument types: 

(com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject) values: [TestObject - 'Object Repository/Trial/ShopSearchResultPage/div-ProductInSearchResult']
Possible solutions: 

findElements(com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.WindowsTestObject), findElement(com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.WindowsTestObject), findElements(com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.WindowsTestObject, com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling), findElement(com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.WindowsTestObject, com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling

)
```

The signature I used for `findElements` seems to be fine but still getting this error. Please help to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather write:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
...

List<WebElement> foundElements = WebUI.findWebElements(findTestObject('Trial/ShopSearchResultPage/div-ProductInSearchResult'))
```

*You can learn more from* [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/document-for-webui-findwebelements-testobject-is-missing/54453)

Hope you get the answer, please let me know if this does not work for you.